# Why can't the mime-types gem (unpacked in vendor/gems) be found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, mime-types

*I'm asking this with the intention of also supplying the answer, since I had a lot of trouble figuring out what was going wrong, and Google wasn't much help - however, since this is StackOverflow, I'm sure that someone will answer it more competently or improve the answer.*

I needed to upgrade a gem for a rails application that I'm working on, which introduced two new dependencies, one of which is `mime-types`.  Working locally, I added the following line to `config/environment.rb`:

```
config.gem 'mime-types', :version => '1.17'
```

For deployment on our server, it's necessary for all gem dependencies to be installed in `vendor/gems`, so I then installed the `mime-types` gem into the current rvm gemset with:

```
gem install mime-types --version 1.17
```

... and unpacked a version of that into `vendor/gems` with:

```
rake gems:unpack
rake gems:unpack:dependencies
```

However, after deploying on the server, I found that when `rake db:migrate` was run, the following error appeared, indicating that the `mime-types` gem couldn't be found (stack trace partially elided):

```
no such file to load -- mime-types
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
[...]
/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
no such file to load -- mime-types
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
[...]
/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
Missing these required gems:
  mime-types = 1.17

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.302 at /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /home/mark/.gem/ruby/1.8, /var/lib/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

However, `mime-types` was present in `vendor/gems/mime-types-1.17`.  Why doesn't rake think that the gem is installed in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A colleague helpfully fixed this problem for me: it seems that Rails expects all the gems in `vendor/gems` to have a particular layout, which `mime-types` doesn't conform to.  The solution is to change the line in `environment.rb` that specifies the dependency on `mime-type` to add the `:lib` option, which should specify a relative path that indicates how to get to the source in the gem:

```
config.gem 'mime-types', :version => '1.17', :lib => 'mime/types'
```

This means to look in `vendor/gems/mime-types-1.17/lib/mime/types` rather than the default based on the gem name, `vendor/gems/mime-types-1.17/lib/mime-types/`

Comment: If you switch to using bundler, which is probably a good idea, you can get the same result using the `:path` option.

Answer (score 1):

just remove `require 'mime-types'` in your ruby file.

as `mime-types` is built in ruby. you don't need to install its gem or include its explicitly.

just use it.
this works for me.